Root password not working after doing a system upgrade from 30 to 31
I have two systems, one on 26 and one on 28. Both upgrade to 30 just fine. When I upgrade to 31 or 32 using dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=31 and then dnf system-upgrade reboot, when I try to login with root password I get access denied. How can I do the upgrade to 31 and beyond and be able to login as root?
